Is there a closed 3-manifold with infinite fundamental group and trivial first homology?
So I know that closed orientable 3-manifolds can be classified into 3 types. I am particularly interested in the ones that have infinity noncyclic fundamental group. Are there examples of these that have trivial first homology? I know there are examples of finite fundamental group, trivial first homology. But what if the fundamental group is infinite?

See this MO-post.

Yes. Any homology 3-sphere besides the Poincare homology sphere has infinite fundamental group. This is remarked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4798/classification-of-homology-3-spheres

Even more is true: if a compact oriented 3-manifold has a finite perfect fundamental group, then it is a homology 3-sphere (and hence the Poincare homology sphere). This follows from an inequality of Hall and the fact this finite group must have a balanced presentation. (Oh, and the Poincare conjecture!)

Some searching around turned up the following: the Brieskorn spheres $\Sigma(p, q, r)$ are known to be integral homology $3$-spheres if $p, q, r$ are relatively prime. Their fundamental groups were apparently calculated by Milnor, and this calculation implies that $\pi_1$ is finite iff
$$\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} > 1.$$
For $p, q, r$ relatively prime this happens iff $(p, q, r) = (2, 3, 5)$ which gives the Poincaré homology sphere. $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} = 1$ is not possible in the relatively prime case, so in the remaining cases $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} < 1$, for example $(p, q, r) = (2, 3, 7)$. Then $\pi_1$ is an infinite discrete subgroup of $\widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$, related to the triangle group with the same parameters.

Thank you for your answer

The Seifert-Weber dodecahedral space is a good example, not only a homology sphere but also one of the first known closed hyperbolic manifolds, and hence has infinite fundamental group.
It is also quite closely related to the Poincaré homology sphere that you alluded to indirectly, and is mentioned directly in the comments. Both are obtained by gluing opposite faces of a dodecahedron: as explained in that link, the Poincare one (with finite fundamental group and universal cover $\mathbb S^3$) is obtained by gluing with a $1/10$ twist; whereas the Seifert-Weber one (with infinite fundamental gorup and universal cover $\mathbb H^3$) is obtained by gluing with a $3/10$ twist.
